# How can I combine field-specific validation and count valid fields on submit?

Tags: jquery, validation

Trying to apply some odd validation rules to a simple form using jquery validator. There are 3 text fields and 2 select fields. In order to submit the form the user must enter data in and/or select from at least 2 fields. Also if the user chooses to enter text into any of the 3 text fields they must enter at least two characters. So there is validation at the "field level" and also at the "form level". At the field level, no problem, can do this on the validator:

```
            // alias minlength
        $.validator.addMethod("cMinlength", $.validator.methods.minlength,
            // leverage parameter replacement for minlength, {0} gets replaced with 2
            $.validator.format("You must enter at least {0} characters in this field."));


        $("#form1").validate(
            {
                debug: true,
                onfocusout: false,
                onkeyup: false,
                onclick: false,
                rules:
                {
                    txtFirstname: { required: false, cMinlength: 2 },
                    txtLastname: { required: false, cMinlength: 2 },
                    txtBusTitle: { required: false, cMinlength: 2 },
                },
```

At the form level I added a validator function to count the fields with data or selections:

```
            $.validator.addMethod('validEntryCount', function (value, element, param) {

            var validFieldCount = 0;

             $('#form1 :input').not(':button, :submit, :hidden').each(function () {

                if ($(this).val() !== "") {
                    validFieldCount++;
                }
            });

            return validFieldCount >= 2; 
        }, 'You must complete at least two fields before searching.');
```

How do I apply 'validEntryCount' at the form level such that it writes the error message below the submit button? I can apply this at the field level as in:

```
                    rules:
                {
                    txtFirstname: { required: false, cMinlength: 2, validEntryCount: true },
                    txtLastname: { required: false, cMinlength: 2 },
                    txtBusTitle: { required: false, cMinlength: 2 },
                },
```

but the error gets written out under the txtFirstname field:

[image: Form with error message]

Or is this futile and I should just code a complete validation function?

Thanks for any assistance.